# IntelliJ IDEA 2017 - Connection error with database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, intellij-idea, connection

I clicked on **View** -> **Tool Windows** -> **Database** and I was trying to connect through **Data Sources**. Then I entered name of host, database, user, password and URL. I remembered to do downloading convenient driver, but when I want to make the test I see "**failed**" next to the button **Test Connection** and the following error:

`Cannot run program "A:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\jre64\bin\java" (in directory "A:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Cannot run program "A:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\jre64\bin\java" (in directory "A:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku`

"Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku." It means in Polish: "File cannot be found."

I updated IntelliJ and I was trying to connect with PostgreSQL and MySQL but unfortunately the problem is the same... Anyone have any similar error?

Comment: The use of `A:` in your application path is curious, `A:` (and `B:`) are historically reserved for floppy disk drives.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thank you for highlighting of the application path. Unfortunately I found out about reserved name drives' after division of memory of hard disk so it to stay that way.
I installed IDE on volume C: and IntelliJ IDEA was working right for a two weeks.